# Weird margin issue in Safari, IE and iOS

Tags: css, positioning

A client's website is showing white space on the right margin of their site and I'm lost on how I should fix.  I've spent some time in Safari using the developer tool's user agent selector and can seem to place the issue.

Here's the site:
http://frasergibsondavis.com/projects/

Oh man, this has been driving me nuts - hoping someone can lend some insight. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the css class `.g960`, the `float:left` and the `width:950px` are somehow conflicting. If you remove either one of them, the margin problem disappears. Notice, the page doesn't look quite right, but that fixes your margin problem.